# Entity Framework model not updating properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a method in my controller which is to meant to check if a certain amount of time has elapsed and if so it is to update a model property and save this to the database. However the model is not being updated and I am unsure why, if anyone can offer any advice? Thanks! Currently the order is being removed from the database but the eventDetails.TicketsRemaining is not being changed.

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Charge(SummaryVm summaryVm)
 {

 if (checkDateTime(summaryVm.orderDate))
  {

  //do something

 }else{

  // get the event being booked from db based on the ID
  Event eventDetails = _eventRepository.GetByID(summaryVm.eventID);

  // get the order being processed from db based on the ID
  Order thisOrder = db.Orders.Find(summaryVm.orderID);

 //update the number of tickets remaining for event returning the number of tickets requested to the available tickets
  eventDetails.TicketsRemaining += summaryVm.ticketQuantity;

 //remove order from db as payment was not received and order was not processed
 db.Orders.Remove(thisOrder);

 //save these db changes
 db.SaveChanges();

 return RedirectToAction("TimeOut", new { id = summaryVm.eventID });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_eventRepository.SaveChanges()
```

You code is odd as you are mixing design patterns...

db should not exist if you created a _eventRepository

You have created two contexts.. and you are not submitting savechanges to the one you changed data in.

**ALTERNATIVELY**

you could fix by doing

```
  Event eventDetails = db.Events.GetByID(summaryVm.eventID);
```

Comment: thanks that makes sense. I was planning on creating an _orderRepository so will I just need to use _eventRepository.SaveChanges() and _orderRepository.SaveChanges() to save the changes to both db tables? Thanks!

Comment: If they shared the same DB context then you would only need to call it 1's from either. I think you should be aiming towards  a unit of work pattern tho. Like you ask, seems weird... I feel you need to do some more research on repos and UOW patterns and sharing on dbcontext life cycles.

Comment: from the look of your code... I would say they dont and then that would make you correct... in that you would need to call save changes for each repo.... but this is not a good design pattern.

Comment: thanks I will look at the design patterns and research using unit of work pattern